# Does the component of vector depend on the orientation of the axes?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, reference-frames, vectors, coordinate-systems

the question was:

> A situation may be described by using different sets of co-ordinate axes having different orientations. Which of the following do not depend on the orientation of the axes?
>
> (a) the value of a scalar
>
> (b) component of a vector
>
> (c) a vector
>
> (d) the magnitude of a vector

and the answer is option -(a) (c) (d)

I did not understand option b although my teacher explained to me as follows:

Sets of co-ordinate axes are simply lines of references to describe the position and orientation of vectors or similar things. Their orientations cannot change (a) the value of scalar, (b) a vector or (d) the magnitude of a vector. But when a vector is resolved along axes, the component is dependent on the angle between the vector and the axis along which it is being resolved. This angle will vary if the orientation of axes is changed. So the component of a vector will depend upon the orientation of the axes.

please explain to me in simple terms with a little bit of illustration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The components of the vector with the xy-axes, $(x_2-x_1, y_2-y_1)$, are not the same as with the x'y'-axes, $(x'_2-x'_1, y'_2-y'_1)$.

[image]

$(x_2-x_1)^2 +  (y_2-y_1)^2 = (x'_2-x'_1)^2 +  (y'_2-y'_1)^2 = (\text{magnitude of vector})^2$

Comment: thank u so much sir .... really well explained !!!

Comment: sir since the components has changed isn't it changing the vector as well? and this is ultimately changing the magnitude too

Comment: @GarimaSingh The vector itself, drawn in grey, stays the same and is totally independent of how the axes are drawn.

Comment: @GarimaSingh The magnitude of the vector does not change. I have updated my answer to show this.

Comment: oh thanks... now I understand it completely.